# I wonder what is exact meaning of "return"

Tags: c#

I've studying reflexive method and dictionary class(I'm nor sure it's correct in English cuz I'm Korean) and there was a example calculating fibonacci in C# book.

```
class Fibonacci
{
    private static Dictionary<int, long> memo = new Dictionary<int, long>();
    
    public static long Get(int i)
    {
        if (i < 0) { return 0; }
        if (i == 1) { return 1; }

        if (memo.ContainsKey(i)) { return memo[i]; }
        else
        {
            long value = Get(i - 2) + Get(i - 1);
            memo[i] = value;
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder which code puts key and value into dictionary list. At i<0 i==0 line I think it seems "return" does that job but at

if (memo.ContainsKey(i)) { return memo[i]; }

here return does its job as passing(handing over?) the code if there is same key in the dictionary list.
So I'm curious what does "return" actually mean. Help!

Comment: `memo[i] = value;` is the only part of the code that sets anything in the dictionary. The `return` statements don't modify the dictionary

Comment: Ah then if (i < 0) { return 0; }
        if (i == 1) { return 1; }  this codes just exist for dividing situation and there isn't 0 in the dictionary list? (because 1 will be added when key is 2)

Comment: @md3sla In the fibonacci, the `1` term is used twice. So yes, it will be added when the key is 2, but it's also used when the key is 1.

Comment: maybe have a look in the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/jump-statements#the-return-statement

Comment: I tried  Console.WriteLine(Fibonacci.Get(1)); and it yielded 1 , I'm confused how key 1 is available although if (i == 0) {return 1} code exists..but I understood which code puts key into dictionary! I really have to read docs to understand mathematical question as you said..

Comment: Ah I finally feagured out precisely what happens in this codes..memorization just saves values and output is yielded by Get so key 1 may have value 1..thanks for helping so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i < 0` and `i == 1` lines do not use the dictionary at all. For those early terms, the dictionary lookup would be slower than the calculation anyway.

The `if (memo.ContainsKey(i)) { return memo[i]; }` line also does not set anything new in the dictionary. It *reads* from the dictionary, but does not write to it, because either the value is already there or we don't know what to write yet. Today, I might update this code to use [`TryGetValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-6.0) instead, in order to save one hash calculation and lookup on success.

The line that actually writes to the dictionary is this:

```
memo[i] = value;
```

Additionally, the reason the dictionary is named `memo` is because the code uses a technique called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: Thanks for helping! I understood which puts key into dictionary. I may have to search more using keyword memorization for study...thanks again!

Comment: @md3sla memoization (no R)

Answer (score 1):

`memo[i] = value;` adds value to the dictionary. To be more precise, it adds the key value pair if the key didn't exist, or overwrites the value for the key if it existed. Take a look:

```
private static Dictionary<int, long> memo = new Dictionary<int, long>();

public static void AddToDictionary(int key, long value)
{
    memo[key] = value;
    foreach (var item in memo)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}: {item.Value}");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Adding 1,2 key-value pair.
1: 2
Adding 1,8 key-value pair.
1: 8
Adding 2,2 key-value pair.
1: 8
2: 2
```

Comment: It really helped me understanding how dictionary list works..thanks! I could find out how 1 is yielded by using your code....thanks again!!

Comment: Please note that this way you either add or update the value. If you don't wish to update your value in your dictionary by accident, you should use [Dictionary.Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.add?view=net-6.0) method.